# HyperlinkedRelatedField DRF does not work with a ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these models:

```
class ExamSheet (models.Model):
    pass

class Exam(models.Model):
    exam_sheet = models.ForeignKey('myapp.ExamSheet',
                               related_name='exams',
                               )
```

Serializer:

```
class ExamBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    exam_sheet = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(queryset=ExamSheet.objects.all(), view_name='examsheet-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = Exam
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'exam_sheet', )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user',)
```

ViewSets:

```
class ExamViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSet):
    queryset = Exam.objects.all()

class ExamSheetViewSet(MultiSerializerViewSet):
    queryset = ExamSheet.objects.all()
```

Routes:

```
app_name = 'exams_api'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'exams', views.ExamViewSet)
router.register(r'exams_sheets', views.ExamSheetViewSet)
urlpatterns = []
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Global app urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('exams_api.urls')),
]
```

GenericViewSet:

```
class MultiSerializerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializers = {
        'default': None,
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializers.get(self.action, self.serializers['default'])
```

But this throws me an error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /api/exams/
>
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "examsheet-detail". You may have failed to include the related model
>   in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

**How can I use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to show a link to a related model in my serializer?**

Comment: From the docs: "__The view name that should be used as the target of the relationship. If you're using the standard router classes this will be a string with the format <modelname>-detail.__" Do you have a view for examsheet detail, that is wired through the Router?

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali updated my question, added ViewSets and routes connected to this models-serializers

Comment: MultiSerializerViewSet is a custom view set I suppose? Can you post its definition as well?

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali posted, but definitely it is not a problem here.

Comment: I can't see whats wrong with this setup. What I'm not sure about is, if you posted the actual code for ExamSheet model, what django does for a model without a field, create a table only with id? Another thing comes to mind is, did you add your router to your urlpatterns like url(r'^', include(router.urls)),? If not, this may be causing the issue as well but aside from these, everything seems ok to me

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali there are couple of fields in the models, but I don't think it also the case - Django even does not see that models. In my url patterns it is: `path('api/', include('exams_api.urls')),`

Comment: I think you also need to wire your router into urlpatterns as I postes in the previous comment

Comment: That is, you also need to include router.urls at a path of your choice

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali updated the question in Routes and Global urls - may be it will be clearer. What should I change?

Comment: Are your routes defined in exams_api/urls.py file? If so, that part seems OK as well.

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali yep, actually app is working good, just this one field type does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. The view_name you set for the hyperlink field `view_name='examsheet-detail`, do you have a view named `examsheet-detail` in your urlconf(mostly urls.py) for that app? If not, after `include(views.someview)`, add `,name='examsheet-detail'` as a third parameter to path.
2. Have you set `app_name` in the specific app's urlsconf? Removing it solved the issue for me.
3. Make sure `<int:pk>` in the url path for that view and not `<int:id>` or something else. Else, set `lookup_field='id'` cos the default is pk.
4. Make sure that view takes in the pk parameter.